# Variable does not exist error when trying to retrieve the value from the list

Tags: apex, soql, query, loop

```
List<SBQQ__QuoteLineConsumptionRate__c> quoteLineConsumptionRates = [SELECT id, SBQQ__LowerBound__c, SBQQ__UpperBound__c, SBQQ__Price__c, SBQQ__QuoteLineConsumptionSchedule__r.SBQQ__QuoteLine__c, SBQQ__QuoteLineConsumptionSchedule__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLineConsumptionRate__c];
for(SBQQ__QuoteLineConsumptionRate__c qlcr : quoteLineConsumptionRates){
    system.debug(qlcr.SBQQ__QuoteLineConsumptionSchedule__r.SBQQ__QuoteLine_c); // Error: Variable does not exist: SBQQ__QuoteLine_c
}
```

When I run the query in query editor, I am able to retrieve `SBQQ__QuoteLineConsumptionSchedule__r.SBQQ__QuoteLine_c` value. Whereas, when i try to loop the list and try to debug the `SBQQ__QuoteLine_c` Id, I am getting the error : `Variable does not exist: SBQQ__QuoteLine_c`

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. `SBQQ__QuoteLine_c` should be `SBQQ__QuoteLine__c`; you missed an underscore.

Comment: That's very silly on my part!

Comment: @kishan's We've all been there, sometimes we just need a second opinion. Glad I could help!